# redis large channel number performance

Tags: php, laravel, performance, caching, redis

I want to use redis for caching.
One dataset is build up from a number of keys. Those keys have a different size. The largest is about 20k heavy.
For the use case it would be best if a combination of those keys made up the redis channel key.
This way I can flush just small part of the data if updates are made.
The larger the set is that is saved in a channel the more caching I will lose.

But I wonder if there is any downside to having a large number of channels.
If I use that largest key alone this is about 20k.
If I take another key that is multiplied by about 15 times. A third channel again could multiply it by 3 currently but might go up to 20 or more.
So that's 6mil channels then.

Do I get into any trouble using many channels?

Example:
I'm caching information about different kinds of vehicles.
So I could make channels like:

1. cars, trucks, bikes, ...
2. blue vehicles, red vehicles
3. blue cars, red cars, blue trucks, red trucks, blue bikes, red bikes, ...
4. ...

Upon flushing the first redis structure by channel I would "lose" all car information or all truck information and so on.
Upon flushing the second structure by channel I would only lose all blue vehicles information ie.
And the last example would only lose all blue car information and so on.
Still even the channel only containing all blue cars would mean there is a lot of blue cars. But on the other structures I would lose aka have to rebuild even more information.

Comment: Can't you just send several messages into channels corresponding to caches you want to invalidate?

Comment: sorry I'm very new to redis and am using it from laravel now. I suppose that's why I did not really get your comment. I'm writing several messages into channels. let's say channels could be cars, bikes, ... or a channel might be blue cars, red cars, ..., blue bikes, red bikes, ... or blue vehicle, red vehicle. those channel contain information about the vehicle size, weight, price, whatever. if I flush a channel I either lose all red vehicle info or just all red bike info etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See docs:

> SUBSCRIBE channel [channel ...]
>
> Available since 2.0.0.
>
> Time complexity: O(N) where N is the number of channels to subscribe
>   to.

-

> PUBLISH channel message
>
> Available since 2.0.0.
>
> Time complexity: O(N+M) where N is the number of clients subscribed to
>   the receiving channel and M is the total number of subscribed patterns
>   (by any client).

So, as you see, time complexity for subscribe doesn't scale with channels count. But for publish does - linearly. Could you afford looping over your channels? Estimate their upper bound, estimate your hardware and other tasks it will run.

### Or consider this alternative:

Use one channel and pass some info on what portion of cache should be invalidated. It could be a bitmap. For example 1st bit is red,second - green,N+1st - car, N+2nd - bus, N+M+1 - new, N+M+2 - used, etc. Set bits in one category means OR, in different categories - AND. Bitmap operations are very fast, so when done right your cache providers shouldn't sweat much parsing it. It would be ideal, if on Redis side you can make channels that would distribute messages to the right data providers. And providers would parse the message and get an instruction on what part to invalidate.